# Is there a way to use ggplot2 to plot survival curves from a svycoxph object?

Tags: ggplot2, survival-analysis

I used [svycoxph](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survey/versions/4.2-1/topics/svycoxph) from the survey package to create an object:

```
object <- svycoxph(Surv(time, status) ~ group, design=design)
```

And then I used predict() as documented [here on page 88](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf) to predict curves:

```
prediction <- predict(object, type="curve", newdata = data.frame(group=c("A", "B")) )
```

Is there a way to use ggplot2 functionality to plot the survival curves from the prediction? I tried using the base plotting features as documented on the same page 88, but I can't tell which line is A and which line is B, and I can't make it match plot templates I have that were made with ggsurvfit().

One other thing I tried was extracting the data from the prediction object and using ggplot(), but I can't tell if I labeled the A and B lines correctly:

```
prediction.data <- data.frame(time=prediction[["1"]][["time"]], 
                              A_surv=prediction[["1"]][["surv"]], 
                              B_surv=prediction[["2"]][["surv"]])

ggplot(prediction.data, aes(x=time)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=A_surv), color="red") + 
  geom_line(aes(y=B_surv), color="blue")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Essentially you need to cajole the predictions into a data frame and use this for the plot.

Here's a full reprex. First we will load the package, create some reproducible sample data with the same names as in your example, and specify a design:

```r
library(survey)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(time = round(c(rexp(50, 0.01), rexp(50, 0.015))),
                 group  = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 50))
df$status <- ifelse(df$time > 60, 0, 1)
df$time[df$time > 60] <- 60

design <- svydesign(id = ~ group, weights = 1, data = df)
```

Now we create our model

```
object <- svycoxph(Surv(time, status) ~ group, data = df, design = design)
```

Now let's get prediction curves for our two levels of `group`

```
preds <- predict(object, newdata = data.frame(group = c("A", "B")), 
                 type = "curve", se = TRUE)
```

The trickiest part is extracting the curves into a data frame

```r
plot_df <- do.call(rbind, 
        Map(function(x, y) cbind(as.data.frame(unclass(x)), group = y),
            preds, c("A", "B")))

plot_df$lower <- exp(log(plot_df$surv) - 1.96 * sqrt(plot_df$varlog))
plot_df$upper <- exp(log(plot_df$surv) + 1.96 * sqrt(plot_df$varlog))
```

Now we are ready to plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(plot_df, aes(time, surv, color = group)) +
  geom_step(linewidth = 1) +
  geom_step(aes(y = lower), linetype = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_step(aes(y = upper), linetype = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orangered", "deepskyblue4")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_y_continuous("Survival", limits = 0:1, labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: When I run the do.call function I get the error "could not find function "predict.svycoxph"

Comment: @Alex are you sure it's that line? `predict.svycoxph` is invoked in the previous line. In any case, you shouldn't get this error if you have `library(survey)` loaded

Comment: yes I'm still getting the same error. The survey package is loaded, and the predict() line runs fine. Could it have something to do with me setting se=FALSE, or using different variable names?

Comment: @Alex it doesn't really make any sense to me - I can't reproduce your error with the example I made up (you can see that I get nice curves). You'll need to provide some actual data and code that reproduces the error.